# Bind to IsEnabled in WPF with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, xaml, viewmodel, caliburn.micro, isenabled

I have a series of WrapPanels within a DockPanel. I want all but the top panel to be disabled at the beginning but all panels to be visible. As the user satisfies conditions in one panel I want to enable another panel. However, I can't figure out how I can bind the IsEnabled property of the WrapPanel (or if I need to the individual elements) to a boolean in my ViewModel. Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry if you can't use normal XAML in Caliburn.Micro (but it seems like you can from doing a quick google search). If you can, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467287/bind-isenabled-property-to-boolean-in-wpf. WrapPanel has an `IsEnabled`-Property as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update2: This works amazingingly! [Adding a convention for IsEnabled to Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044051/adding-a-convention-for-isenabled-to-caliburn-micro)

Update: Oops I lied. It keeps resetting all of my XAML by having an object of the same type in the ViewModel.

> Just realized that I can just create an instance of what I am trying to >enable/disable in the ViewModel and from that access the IsEnabled property. Not >direct but works!