# WPF - How Enable Button on Check the RadioButton using Validation Rules

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, button, radio-button

I just started learning WPF, sorry in advance for any silly question. I want to enable a button if there is no validation errors for all the inputs. This is my example input window:

```
<StackPanel>

    ...rest of my page

    <Label>Age:</Label>
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <Label>Options:</Label>
    <RadioButton>Option one</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton>Option two</RadioButton>
    <Button Name="btnOK" MinWidth="40" Command="c:CustomCommands.Enter">Ok</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

In my behind-code I have the method CanExecute for the Button as:

```
private void EnterCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = isValid(sender as DependencyObject);
}

private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) && LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj).OfType<DependencyObject>().All(IsValid);
}
```

I have seen on google people adding validation rule to one RadioButton only, like in [Validation Rule for Radio buttons wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596373/validation-rule-for-radio-buttons-wpf).

what I need is when all the RadioButton are unselected it should add a Validation Error so the Button would be disabled by the IsValid method. If any RadioButton is selected the Button would be enable if Age is also "ok".

Also, I need to know how it would be in the model-view class for the RadioButton part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to Stígandr's answer in this topic ([Bind IsEnabled property to Boolean in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467287/bind-isenabled-property-to-boolean-in-wpf)) you just need to create a property in your viewModel and bind Radiobutton IsEnabled / IsChecked property to this property.

You can set that property in your method.

```
private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) && LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj).OfType<DependencyObject>().All(IsValid);
    yourProperty = value;
}
```

then it is going to update your UI.

In your case ,

Create a dependency property that binds to yourProperty in your viewModel.

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty IsFormValidProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsFormValid",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(YourControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValidationChanged))
        );

privatestaticvoid OnValidationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    // here , if e.newValue is true then
    //you can set button's IsEnabled property to true.
}
```

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, thanks for you help. I am not sure if this solution would solve my problem. The button should be enable only if there is no validation error in any of the inputs besides the radiobuttons. It is controlled by the CanExecute command method. You suggested creating another method to control the visibility, then sometimes it will be enabled by the _IsValid_, and sometimes by the _OnValidationChanged_? Also, I believed you meant using _yourProperty = value;_ before the return, right?